# First two lines of the first paragraph on each page have an extra space

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I'm working with an existing document in MS Word 2010 that has an issue with the first paragraph on each page. On the first two lines of each paragraph, the line has an extra space. This is not an indention or any sort of paragraph spacing that I can tell. I've tried all my normal methods (paragraph settings, justification, document property settings) for removing this extra space and I cannot seem to find a way to remove it. Even when showing paragraph marks, it does not show there is a space there - it's blank.

Can anyone help?

[image]

[image]

Example file:
https://filebin.net/huvc1a20ndeyrj43

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the paragraph properties dialog, first tab.

Comment: Just added an image to the same link (above)

Comment: A mystery. Can you post a small document?

Comment: Added to post above

Comment: Ahh, there's a text box from the header that's inside the body of the file. Very curious how that happened. Thanks for the help! See image here: https://imgur.com/a/4DvFpYe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a clever use of
[Word Frames](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/creating-frames-pages),
which are just place-holders.

This frame was included in the header, but the header size was calculated
to just terminate above it. Double-clicking on it will show its properties:

[image]